# Django: How do I serialize a nested relationship when the nested target has inherited subtypes?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I create a serializer for a nested relationship, with a transaction, where the nested relationship has several child types? I’ve read through the documentation and that doesn’t seem to be well-covered.

We have an application for insuring homeowners, with the following structure:

```py
class Homeowner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null = True)
    
class Property(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)
    # lots more removed. Not an abstract model.

class House(Property):
    number_of_floors = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    
class Condo(Property):
    has_doorman = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

(This is strictly for show; the different home types have a *lot* of discount or liability fields.) For years, the way we’ve done this is that we’ve entered the property by hand, and then entered the homeowner as two separate stages, linking them with a search-for-properties dialog on the homeowner page. It’s always been a zero-or-one-to-one relationship: A property may have zero or one homeowners, and a homeowner may have zero-or-one properties.

The orders have come down to create a unified experience that the homeowner can fill out themself: enter the whole thing, homeowner and property, and validate them together, rolling everything back if anything fails. Sadly, too much depends on the existing structure to re-arrange the models. As far as I know (it’s been a few years since I wrestled with Django), if I just had a property it would be as simple as:

```py
class PolicySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property = PropertySerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Homeowner
        fields = ['name', 'property']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        property_data = validated_data.pop('property')
        property = Property.objects.create(**property_data)
        Homeowner.objects.create(property=property, **validated_data)
        return homeowner
```

It’s fairly trivial to detect what kind of property form the homeowner filled out, but once I know that, how do I write the `create()` method to route to right kind of Property subtype model?

And if the Homeowner object fails to validate, how to I ensure the Property object isn’t just left lying around? Is that automatically handled now, or should I decorate the `create()` method with `@transaction.atomic`?

Answer (score 0):

you should define serializers for each property subtype(House and Condo) then create a serializer for the property model that will dynamically determine the subtype based on the input data and finally you should create the Homeowner serializer, including the property serializer.

your property serializer should be like this:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ['number_of_floors']


class CondoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Condo
        fields = ['has_doorman']
```

now we can create the property serializer that will handle the different sybtypes:

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Custom field to hold the subtype serializer
    subtype_serializer = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['address', 'subtype', 'subtype_serializer']

    def get_subtype_serializer(self, obj):
        # Determine the subtype of the property and return the corresponding serializer
        if isinstance(obj, House):
            return HouseSerializer(instance=obj).data
        elif isinstance(obj, Condo):
            return CondoSerializer(instance=obj).data
        else:
            return {}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        subtype_data = validated_data.pop('subtype', None)

        # Determine the subtype of the property based on the input data
        subtype = None
        if subtype_data:
            if subtype_data.get('number_of_floors'):
                subtype = 'house'
            elif subtype_data.get('has_doorman') is not None:
                subtype = 'condo'

        # Create the Property object
        property_obj = Property.objects.create(subtype=subtype, **validated_data)

        # Create the specific subtype object and associate it with the Property object
        if subtype == 'house':
            House.objects.create(property=property_obj, **subtype_data)
        elif subtype == 'condo':
            Condo.objects.create(property=property_obj, **subtype_data)

        return property_obj
```

and finally the Homeowner serializer:

```
class HomeownerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property = PropertySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Homeowner
        fields = ['name', 'property']

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        property_data = validated_data.pop('property')
        property_serializer = PropertySerializer(data=property_data)
        property_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        homeowner = Homeowner.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Create the Property object and its subtype
        property_obj = property_serializer.save()

        # Associate the Property object with the Homeowner object
        homeowner.property = property_obj
        homeowner.save()

        return homeowner
```

you should use `@transaction.atomic` decorator to make sure that if any part of the creation process fails the entire transaction will be rolled back.

there might be some validation errors in you views.py that should be handle

you can make it more dynamic and scalable by using model inheritance and serializers to automatically handel the subtypes

we can use model inheritance like this:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    # you can add common fields and methods for all property types here.

class House(Property):
    number_of_floors = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Condo(Property):
    has_doorman = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and now we can use serializers to handle the different subtypes:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ['number_of_floors']

class CondoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Condo
        fields = ['has_doorman']

class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['address']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # detect the subtype dynamically and use the appropriate serializer
        if isinstance(instance, House):
            serializer = HouseSerializer(instance=instance)
        elif isinstance(instance, Condo):
            serializer = CondoSerializer(instance=instance)
        else:
            serializer = super().to_representation(instance)
        return serializer.data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # detect the subtype dynamically and create the appropriate instance
        property_type = data.get('type', None)
        if property_type == 'house':
            serializer = HouseSerializer(data=data)
        elif property_type == 'condo':
            serializer = CondoSerializer(data=data)
        else:
            serializer = super().to_internal_value(data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return serializer.validated_data

class PolicySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property = PropertySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Homeowner
        fields = ['name', 'property']

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        property_data = validated_data.pop('property')
        property_instance = Property.objects.create(**property_data)
        homeowner = Homeowner.objects.create(property=property_instance, **validated_data)
        return homeowner
```

now you don't need to manually update the if-clauses for each subtype instead the serializers automatically detect the subtype based on the `type` field provided in data the serializer handle the rest based on the detected subtype.

note that you should ass a `type` field to the incoming data to determine the subtype.

remember to include the `type` field when sending data to the api so that the serializer can correctly identify the subtype like this:

```
{
    "name": "Kiarash Gh",
    "property": {
        "type": "house",
        "number_of_floors": 1,
        "address": "256 Main St"
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: So for every subtype of property I want to ensure (like, if we start selling in New York, they have a separate property category for "co-op"), I have to add something to the `if` clauses?  I can't automatically detect the subtypes and route their data to them? That seems... suboptimal?

Comment: I have edited the answer, I hope it helps.